# Is there anyway to read grib file without download it?(directly from the link)

Tags: python, grib-2, noaa

```
grbs = pygrib.open(
   'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/north-american-mesoscale-model/access/historical/forecast/202001/20200101/nam_218_20200101_0600_024.grb2')
grb = grbs.read(1)[0]
```

This is what I am trying to do, but it gives me the following error [image]

The link has no issue, since i can use that link and download the file in the local machine, and use pygrib.open to read file from local machine, But now I am having trouble to read file directly from the link. I read through pygrib documentation, it seems like they did not provide a way to do that. Is there any way can read grib file drectly from link?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GDAL's Network Based File Systems](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#network-based-file-systems). You simply have to add the `/vsicurl/` prefix to the URL. Then you can access the data and all their properties.

For example:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

ds = gdal.Open('/vsicurl/https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/north-american-mesoscale-model/access/historical/forecast/202001/20200101/nam_218_20200101_0600_024.grb2')
data = ds.ReadAsArray()
```